# Как сделать чтобы в таблице tr растягивались

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, делаю таблицу. В этом коде видно что второй row не растягивается

```css
table {
  width:100%;
}
table td {
  height:100px;
}
table tr {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Как сделать чтобы `tr` растягивались так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что второй растягивается. Как это сделать и в каком направлении копать

Comment: извините за ошибки я только проснулся у нас сейчас 12:25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О, придумал хак, не меняющий разметку.
Только делать так всё равно не надо!

```css
table, tbody {
  display: block;
}

tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

tr + tr {
  margin-top: -2px; /* не удваивать cellspacing */
}

td {
  height: 94px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

При той разметке, которая есть в вопросе, нормальными способами - **никак**.
По-хорошему, надо таблицу заменить на другие решения.
Но если надо обязательно сохранить таблицу и структуру разметки, то так:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  height: 94px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Современное решение с использованием flexbox:

```css
.block {
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
}

.cell {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 94px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```